# Как записать данные из поля input в json файл?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

Мне нужно из полей login и password сохранить данные в файл .json при помощи Java Spring

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Login Page</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .login-container {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 20px;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      width: 300px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .login-container h2 {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .form-group {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    label {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    input[type="text"],
    input[type="password"] {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    input[type="submit"] {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    input[type="submit"]:hover {
      background-color: #45a049;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login-container">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form action="/login" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Где вы собираетесь сохранять файл и главное -- зачем?

Comment: И по какому событию вы хотите это делать? Если при отправки формы, то покажите ваш java код, который эту форму обрабатывает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того что бы записать данные в файл вы можете использовать `ObjectMapper` класс. Пример кода

```java
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity formLogin(LoginData loginData){

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String jsonLoginData = mapper.getWriter().write(loginData); // Преобразуем в JSON
  writeInFile(jsonLoginData);   // Записываем данные в файл 

  // Если используйте Spring Security не забудьте аутентифицировать пользователя 
  Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginData.getUsername(), loginData.getPassword());
  Authentication authenticated = authenticationManager.authenticate(auth);          
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticated);

  return ResponseEntity.ok().build();

}
```

Данный код получит данные из формы авторизации и запишет эти данные в виде JSON в файл. Обратите внимание что так делать **небезопасно**. Если есть прямая необходимость записывать данные авторизации то используйте хеширование перед записью данных в файл. Также если вы используйте кастомную логику для авторизации , то не забудьте указать это в конфигурации Spring

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .apply(customAuthenticationConfigurer());
    // ...
}

public CustomAuthenticationConfigurer customAuthenticationConfigurer() {
    return new CustomAuthenticationConfigurer();
}
```

Если вы просто хотите свою страницу авторизации то можете удалить лишний код и оставить только `antMatchers("/login").permitAll()` в цепочке настройки безопасности. Надеюсь смог вам помочь